# Regex remove characters after space in each line

Tags: regex

I have a text file with 50k lines like this

```
word1 1 23
word2 43 23
word3 197
word4
```

and need a way to make it look like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

So I need a way to remove every character behind the first space in each line.
How do I do this?

Comment: Regular expressions are a method for *matching* text.  If you want to DO something with that text, like remove it, you need to use regular expression functions within some kind of language or software.  What is your environment?  Are we in PHP/Python/Perl?  Vi?  Unix command line?  Adobe Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple solutions.

**Solution 1: Vim**

Open the file in [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php), then run:

`:%s/\s.*//g`

**Solution 2: sed**

`sed "s/ .*//g" < input_file > output_file`

Cannot do this on windows tho.

**Solution 3: Excel/Calc/Numbers**

Import the file in OpenOffice/MSOffice/etc.
You can set space as a delimiter.
But this is a slower and less fun. :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good. In this case I might even prefer the not-so-fun way. ;) I couldn't figure out how to set the delimiter to space. It just imports every line in the first column.

Answer (score 3):

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat input.txt 
word1 1 23
word2 43 23
word3 197
word4
[ghoti@pc ~]$ awk '{print $1}' input.txt 
word1
word2
word3
word4
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sed 's/ .*//' input.txt 
word1
word2
word3
word4
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cut -d\  -f1 input.txt 
word1
word2
word3
word4
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish I was still using Linux. :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using excel, or a spreadsheet to do this instead if it's a one-off.

Just import a file, and set the delimiter as a space character. Then you can delete all but the first column and save again as a text file.

Comment: Yes, it is a one-off. I tried importing the txt file with Excel, but it does not separate the words by spaces. Could you explain how to do this? Sorry, I don't work with Excel or Regex very often.